# CGAL Cylinder Detection in Point Cloud

Tags: cgal

I have Point Clouds of excavation sites and want to detect the pipes inside. However, playing around with the examples ([RANSAC](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Shape_detection/examples/Shape_detection/efficient_RANSAC_with_parameters.cpp) where only use Cylinder, and [Region Growing](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Shape_detection/examples/Shape_detection/region_growing_cylinders_on_point_set_3.cpp)). When trying around with the parameters, I have not yet achieved any useful results. Here and there RANSAC finds parts of the pipe correctly, but using the region growing approach nothing reasonable is found. Does anyone have tips on how I can find suitable parameters?